# Model state validation error when content type parameter is []

Tags: c#, parameters, asp.net-web-api2, modelstate

When I send a JSON to WebApi controller I have this error from Model Validation:

```
Cannot populate list type System.Net.TrackingStringDictionary. Path 'Attachments[0].Item3.Parameters', line 1, position 53197
```

My JSON string is:

```
"Attachments":[{"Item3":{"Boundary":null,"CharSet":null,"MediaType":"application/pdf","Name":null,"Parameters":[]}}]
```

and the error at `line 1, position 53197` is `[`.

This is my model Attachments:

[image]

and this is my parameter:

[image]

I try to put value on parameter array but it doesn't work.

I try to change media type but it doesn't work.
The position error is always `[`

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is your model a `List` or an `Array`? shows the model in the question

Comment: @asd my Attachments is a List and my Parameters is a Dictionaty

Comment: A Dictionary should not have `[]`. It structure is `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}` https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm#DeserializingDictionaries

Comment: @asd I add two images with the model

Comment: @asd do you have a solution?

Comment: I answered you in the previous comment. The structure of a dictionary should not have []. This link explains how to send a dictionary. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm#DeserializingDictionaries